# Conditional ranking, or conditional numbering in R?

Tags: r

I want to number tournaments for different players. The basic dataset is listed below. I want to number each tournament that a given player has participated in so that I can account for people missing tournaments.

```
Player.ID  Tournament.ID
21633      2018010
21909      2018010
21633      2018020
```

Ideally, I want to start with the highest Tournament.ID value and give it a value of 1, then count up as the Tournament.ID goes down. But I only want it to count for the specific Player.ID.

There's a chance I'm not explaining this well, but I'm brand new so your patience is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What would be the expected output? You have two `Player.ID == 21633` but with different `Tournament.ID` values, how would you count?

Comment: So for the highest value for Player.ID == 21633, the value would be 1, the next highest would be 2, etc. All of the different Player.ID numbers would follow that format, ideally.

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. You should provide an example of expected output

Comment: I'm not sure how to provide an example since I can't figure out how to do it. I want each Tournament.ID to be numbered (from highest to lowest) but I want it to be done for each Player.ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = unique(data.frame(Player.id=sample(c(1:5),20,replace=TRUE),
                Tournament.ID=sample(c(1:3),20,replace=TRUE)))

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
result <- df %>% arrange(desc(Tournament.ID),Player.id) %>%
  group_by(Player.id) %>% 
  mutate(Count = dense_rank(desc(Tournament.ID)))

result
# A tibble: 13 x 3
# Groups:   Player.id [5]
   Player.id Tournament.ID Count
       <int>         <int> <int>
 1         2             3     1
 2         3             3     1
 3         4             3     1
 4         5             3     1
 5         1             2     1
 6         2             2     2
 7         4             2     2
 8         5             2     2
 9         1             1     2
10         2             1     3
```